# Getting data from an avro file for every row in a spark dataframe column

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to process one of the columns in my dataframe and retrieve a metric from the avro file corresponding to each entry.

Basically, I want to do the following:

1. read in each row of the Path column which is the path to an avro file
2. Read in the avro file as a dataframe & get the accuracy metric, which is in the form of a Struct
3. create a new column called Accuracy, which has the accuracy metric

This can also been seen as applying `spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(avro_path)`
but for every row in the `Path` column.
This is my input dataframe:

```
+----------+-----+--------------------------+
|timestamp |Model|         Path             |
+----------+-----+--------------------------+
|11:02     |Vgg  |projects/Vgg/results.avro |
|18:31     |Dnet |projects/Dnet/results.avro|
|15:54     |Rnet |projects/Rnet/results.avro|
|12:19     |ViT  |projects/ViT/results.avro |
+----------+-----+--------------------------+
```

I want this to be my output dataframe:

```
+----------+-----+--------------------------+-----------+
|timestamp |Model|         Path             | Accuracy  |
+----------+-----+--------------------------+-----------+
|11:02     |Vgg  |projects/Vgg/results.avro |   0.72    | 
|18:31     |Dnet |projects/Dnet/results.avro|   0.78    |
|15:54     |Rnet |projects/Rnet/results.avro|   0.75    |
|12:19     |ViT  |projects/ViT/results.avro |   0.82    |
+----------+-----+--------------------------+-----------+
```

I have tried using udf, but I guess you cant load in dataframes in a udf.

```
val get_auc: (String => String) = (avro_path: String) => {
    
     val auc_avro_file = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(avro_path)
     val auc = auc_avro_file.select("metrics.Accuracy").first.toString
     auc

}
val auc_udf = udf(get_auc)
val auc_path = models_df.withColumn("Accuracy", auc_udf(col("avro_path")))
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (string) => string)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.writeFields_0_1$(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:429)
  ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:49)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:46)
  ... 20 more
```

Is there any other way I can do this? Like using a map or a for loop?

Edit: tried using input_file_name based on one of the answers below:

```
val paths_col = auc_path.select($"Path")  
val avro_paths = paths_col.withColumn("filename", input_file_name())
```

But this is giving me a url to a completely different avro file in the new column, which isnt what I want.

```
+----------+-----+--------------------------+------------------------------------+
|timestamp |Model|         Path             |          different_output_Path     |            
+----------+-----+--------------------------+------------------------------------+
|11:02     |Vgg  |projects/Vgg/results.avro |projects/models/all_model_runs.avro |
|18:31     |Dnet |projects/Dnet/results.avro|projects/models/all_model_runs.avro |
|15:54     |Rnet |projects/Rnet/results.avro||projects/models/all_model_runs.avro|
|12:19     |ViT  |projects/ViT/results.avro |projects/models/all_model_runs.avro |
+----------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How do I still get the `metrics.Accuracy` part in each avro file?

Comment: Join not an option?

Comment: But I dont have the accuracies already as a column. I need to retrieve them from each avro file using the ```Path``` column. I got these 4-5 files after filtering based on various criteria. So I selectively want the accuracies only for these models/avro files

Comment: Need to show more data.

Comment: Show diff in file names pls.

Comment: Added at the end of the post. I got some other information such as execId, etc. from the ```all_model_runs.avro```, due to which its possibly going back to the same file. However, I dont need  ```all_model_runs.avro``` anymore.

Comment: Odd but must be some obvious reason.

Comment: Like path and file.

Comment: Pls show files in dir.

Answer (score 0):

Read the avro file as dataframe and store the path for row:

```
...
val dfWithCol = df.withColumn("filename",input_file_name())
...
```

Then JOIN appropriately.

Comment: Having a little trouble understanding. Does df here correspond to my ```Path``` column consisting of the avro file paths? How do I still get the ```metrics.Accuracy``` part in each avro file?

I tried the following:

```val paths_col = auc_path.select($"Path")

val avro_paths = paths_col.withColumn("filename", input_file_name())```

But this is giving me a url to different avro files in the new column, which isnt helping